# How do I run a block of if statements, and update state for each in React native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

In react native, I have a picker for selecting values, Yes/No/Maybe, I want to check if Yes/No/Maybe.
I created a function like this, but if I run the function, even though all is Yes. The value of risk remains 1

```
const [risk, setRisk]  = useState(0)

const check = () => {
    if(cough === 'Yes'){
    setRisk(risk+1)
  }

  if(fever ==='Yes'){
    setRisk(risk+1)
  }

  if(breathing ==='Yes'){
    setRisk(risk+1)
  }

  if(travel ==='Yes'){
    setRisk(risk+1)
  }

  if(gather ==='Yes'){
    setRisk(risk+1)
  }
  if(contact ==='Yes'){
    setRisk(risk+1)
  }

  if(neighbor ==='Yes'){
    setRisk(risk+1)
  }

  if(hospital ==='Yes'){
    setRisk(risk+1)
  }
  if(neighbor === 'Maybe'){
    setRisk(risk+0.5)
  }
  if(contact === 'Maybe'){
    setRisk(risk+0.5)
  }
  if(gather === 'Maybe'){
    setRisk(risk+0.5)
  }
  if(travel === 'Maybe'){
    setRisk(risk+0.5)
  }

  console.log('risk level is ' + risk)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There might be a "better" way to do this, but you could define a `newRisk` at the beginning of your `check()` function and mutate that value. Then set it at the end using the hook-provided function.

Example:

```
const [risk, setRisk]  = useState(0)

const check = () => {
  let newRisk = risk;

  if(cough === 'Yes'){
    newRisk += 1;
  }

  if(fever ==='Yes'){
    newRisk += 1;
  }

  if(breathing ==='Yes'){
    newRisk += 1;
  }

  if(travel ==='Yes'){
    newRisk += 1;
  }

  if(gather ==='Yes'){
    newRisk += 1;
  }
  if(contact ==='Yes'){
    newRisk += 1;
  }

  if(neighbor ==='Yes'){
    newRisk += 1;
  }

  if(hospital ==='Yes'){
    newRisk += 1;
  }
  if(neighbor === 'Maybe'){
    newRisk += 0.5;
  }
  if(contact === 'Maybe'){
    newRisk += 0.5;
  }
  if(gather === 'Maybe'){
    newRisk += 0.5;
  }
  if(travel === 'Maybe'){
    newRisk += 0.5;
  }

  setRisk(newRisk);

  console.log('risk level is ' + newRisk)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You are assuming the `setRisk` method to be synchronous which is not. You are getting this behavior as the `setRisk` method is asynchronous.

The state update method which is returned by the `useState` hook is asynchronous, and this does not immediately reflect or re-render your component. But there is a guarantee that the state will be updated, which will result in re-render. This behavior is very similar to the class component `setState` method. (Read [here](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/14259) and [here](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/14259#issuecomment-439632622)). React may also batch the `setRisk` calls to avoid multiple re-renders(read more here), and thus to do this, React can't simply run your `setRisk` method synchronously. Having said that, you can achieve your end result by summing up all the values in a single variable and then setting the state, as in @segFault's answer.